# Find the number just below the required parameter in python

Tags: python

```
 number_of_dimension  declared_block_size  actual_block_size   declared_maximum_bl
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
              10               23100                5377      10924293219840
```

Suppose if I ask for `actual_block_size`, I should get `5377`.
Please note that I am reading from a normal text file and not from CSV file.

Comment: How does your file look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is your file parse-able by the python csv module ie tab delimited?

Comment: Its a simple .txt file with many lines of text and in between them there are columns and rows like in question. I have to first search for the column name in the file, such as "actual_block_size" as above and then I need to write to another file the data that is below "actual_block_size" that is 5377.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary to point each key to its according value:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    fields = f.readline().split(' ')  # get the titles from the first line
    values = f.readline().split(' ')  # get the values from the second line
dictionary = dict(zip(fields, keys))  # create a dictionary where each field points to its value
print dictionary['actual_block_size'] # you can access each value by its key (title)
```

Comment: But my text file is also having normal lines of data, which are not in table format. Also you skipped the line with ------------------------------------ which is actually there